# What's Flash Lite at all?

Tags: actionscript, flash, flashlite

I've long thought of Flash Lite as something similar to **actionscript**, for mobile browsers.

But today I tried to create a Flash Lite project in flash cs5 but found it seems to be some kind of **Flash Player** ?

Which is the case ?

If it's the latter case, is **actionscript** for **Flash Lite** the same as **actionscript** for **Flash Player** or has some kind of difference?

Comment: Flash Lite runs in the mobile version of Flash Player: Flash Lite. There are multiple versions of Flash Lite, but roughly it like using actionscript 1.0 since the flash 4 days(eval() rings a bell :P) and has the mobile specific actions(softkeys,slighltly extended fscommand), etc.

Comment: You mean **Flash Lite** stands for both **Flash Player** and **actionscripts** ?

Comment: Flash Lite just "stands" for a lite version of Flash.  It still uses Actionscript but it's usually a few steps behind Flash "normal."

Comment: Is the `Actionscript` that flash lite uses the same as the one Flash normal uses ?

Comment: Flash Lite uses a subset of AS1/AS2

Answer (score 1):

Flash lite is indeed a stripped down flash player for embedded devices.  With the latest round of smartphones using the "real" flash player you may be better off ignoring it.  (I do flash lite development in my day job for around 60,000 devices worldwide, but I still recommend bypassing it and just concentrating on Flash 10+)

Basically, take all the advanced features out of flash and make it small enough to fit on now archaic devices.  (Sorry, it's the truth!)

Comment: So Flash lite is a player for actionscript, then is the actionscript for Flash lite the same as the actionscript for Flash player ?

Comment: For Flash 10+, the sad news is that it's only supported by mobile phones that has at least `ARM v7`

Comment: It depends on what flash lite version you are targeting... Flash Lite only has support for Actionscript 2.  Flash Lite 2 has most of the equivalent functionality of Flash 7 and Flash Lite 3 has most of the capability of Flash 9 (AS2 only.)  Flash Lite 3 adds support for video and some other things, but it sticks to Actionscript 2 and will not play anything written in AS3.

There is a FAQ here that may answer more questions: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashlite/faq/

Comment: thanks for the reply!So only Flash Lite 3/4 can be used to play video streams ? I'm actually now porting an net stream application to Flash lite.

Comment: Flash 3.1 supports H.264.  I do not know of any other support though.  Sorry.